Wifi adaptor not found ASUSVIVOBOOK 15X OLED
Inbuilt Wifi adaptor not working in ubuntu 22.04 also bluetooth not working .my kernal version is 6.10 latest. It is showing NETWORK UNCLAIMED The product is saying (Mediatech Corp.) No specific version and when i checked wifi is not blocked. And i am not using it in dual boot. I am a newbie in ubuntu please help me solve this in detail cause i know only a little bit.

6.10 kernel is at present not supported on any version of Ubuntu. Your question should say why you changed the default kernel.

What should i do
